# Base 64 image into uiimage - Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimageview, base64

I'm trying to insert a base 64 image into UIImage in Objective-C I do the following:

I have the user's image into a NSURL

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: [fetchDefaults objectForKey:@"img"]];
```

Then I cast the url, into a NSString

```
NSString *string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",url];
```

Then I clean the string, and add the prefix "data:application/octet-stream;base64," also tried with "data:image/jpg;base64,"

```
NSMutableString *tempStr = [NSMutableString stringWithString:string];
            [tempStr replaceOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [tempStr length])];
              NSString *temp = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"data:application/octet-stream;base64,%@",tempStr] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

And finally the string is cast to an NSData to be inserted into UImage

```
NSData *dat = [[NSData alloc]initWithBase64EncodedString:temp options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];
            [avatar setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:dat]];
```

Despite of value of dat is not nil, when I set the image to the UIImage the image isn't showed, any idea of what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Then I cast the url, into a NSString`, that's not a cast, and you should use `NSString *string= [url absoluteString];`, no? And what you do make no sense at all. Why adding `@"data:application/octet-stream;base64,%@"` should make it an UIImage? What is happening from the with the URL? Could you give us the value of `[fetchDefaults objectForKey:@"img"]`? If it's an URL (really), it'd make sense that you need to download it.

Comment: in `fetchDefaults` I have a string something like that `iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMgAAADICAMAAACahl6sAAAAq1BMVEX///8ARIvvhhs7cKb7/P3G0uIAQooERo0PTpG9zN5Meanl6fHN2+n//vyYs9Dy9fn+ ... TkSuQmCC´ this string I need to add `@"data:application/octet-stream;base64,%@"´ to indicate that is a base 64 string, then I need to add into UIImageView but I do not know if its correct the way I'm doing that.

Comment: "I need to add @"data:application/octet-stream;base64,%@"´" Why? Not specially. If it's already correctly done, you don't have to to that.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you have your base64 string in `fetchDefaults`.

```
/*Get base64 string*/
NSString *base64 = [fetchDefaults objectForKey:@"img"];
```

<del>Use this NSData category: https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/40028750/</del>

```
/*Convert base64 to NSData object*/
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:base64];
/*Convert data to UIImage object*/
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
```

Comment: `initWithBase64EncodedString:options:` already exists since iOS7. Not need for a category.

Comment: Sorry about that. I haven't been using Objective-C for a long time.

Comment: Is this just that I needed! I'm implemented this and everything is OK! Thanks buddies!